# F# Shorthand for mapping over a list of records & grabbing a named value

Tags: f#

I'm mapping over a list of records in F# and grabbing a named value:

```ml
type Person = { FirstName: string; LastName: string }

let people = [
    { FirstName = "Whitney"; LastName = "Houston" }
    { FirstName = "Tina"; LastName = "Turner" }
    { FirstName= "Donna"; LastName = "Summer" }
]

people |> List.map (fun person -> person.LastName)
```

In the Elm language, you can do something like

```
people |> List.map .LastName
```

Is some sort of shorthand like that possible in F#?

Comment: No, F# does not have anything similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an open language suggestion: [Allow _.Property or (.Property) shorthand accessor functions #506](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/506) to add this feature. It is approved in principle and still being actively discussed.